# Refetching JSON events in FullCalendar on Salesforce

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar with Salesforce and multiple users.  Because of the SF limitations I have to use Remote Action and JSON string.  Everything is working great except that I cannot refresh the JSON list when changes are being made.  I have created a custom button to perform the AddEventSource and/or RemoveEventSource and/or run the event function, and many other combinations and nothing works.  It will only grab what is already in the JSON string. I need it go out to the controller and get new data to render.  I can get this done with a general submit button but then the user is taken back to the current date and not the one that was edited.  I just need to refetch the evt object. I'm sure it is something simple that I am missing but it has been 6 months and I am at a loss.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarPrintCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"/>
```

```
   function getEventData() {                         // records are retrieved from soql database
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.PWMFullCalendarController.eventdata}',  // controller and method names
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                evt =  JSON.parse(result);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({       // html element and library name
                    events: evt,

                    height: 650,                        
             customButtons: {
                btnPrint: {
                    text: 'Print',
                    click: function() {
                        printPage();
                    }
                   },
                btnRefresh: {
                    text: 'Refresh',
                    click: function() {
                   // Clear all events
                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', evt);

                         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', evt);
                         alert('Refresh');
                    }
                   }
                },


             header: {

                left: 'prev,next today btnRefresh',

                center: 'title',

                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay btnPrint'

                     },

             defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
             eventClick: function(event) {                    
                if (event.url ) {
                    window.open(event.url, "Edit Event", "height=500,width=900,menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no");
                    return false;}
                                         },

            dayClick: function(date, jsevent, view) {
                var startdate = date.format("MM/DD/YYYY");
                var starttime = date.format("hh:mm a");
                window.open ("https://prestigewm.my.salesforce.com/00U/e?StartDateTime=" + startdate + 
                                     "&StartDateTime_time=" + starttime + "&EndDateTime=" + startdate + "&EndDateTime_time=" + starttime,
                                      "New Event", "height=500,width=1000,menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no");

                                                     },
                                                                     editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            slotDuration: '00:30:01',
        businessHours: {start: '07:00', end:'20:00'}


                }) 
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') { 
                console.log(event.message);
            } else {
                console.log(event.message);
            }
        }, 
        {escape: false}
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getEventData();
});
</script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [defaultDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/).

eg.: defaultDate: '2017-05-07'

when you know exact day which you want to display in fullcalendar.
I hope it helps.